# How to compare date in xml attribute in sql server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have an XML data in a column of SQL server table. The XML data looks like:

```
<MainTag dateCreated="2/6/2020 9:22:48 AM">

</MainTag>
```

I am writing a query to fetch the data from XML which has latest dateCreated.
I tried using order by clause but since the date is stored as string, wrong XML is fetched.

Query I tried:

```
SELECT TOP 1 tbl.Id,
c.value(''@dateCreated'',''VARCHAR(max)'') AS [dateCreated]
FROM tbl
CROSS APPLY tbl.Column.nodes(''/MainTag[1]'') AS t(c)
order by c.value(''@dateCreated'', ''VARCHAR(max)'') DESC;
```

If two XMLs are like:

```
<MainTag dateCreated="2/6/2020 9:22:48 AM"> and <MainTag dateCreated="5/3/2016 8:12:37 AM">
```

Then Xml which is fetched is

```
<MainTag dateCreated="5/3/2016 8:12:37 AM">
```

but I want

```
<MainTag dateCreated="2/6/2020 9:22:48 AM">
```

to be fetched.

Not sure how to do that.

Comment: Why are all your literal strings wrapped in double single quotes (`''`)?

Comment: The select statement is inside quotes

Comment: *"The select statement is inside quotes"*, *Why*? That implies you're using dynamic SQL, which implies a layer of complexity we're missing.

Comment: It is a dynamic query

Comment: how to do it if it is not a dynamic sql

Comment: Well, you've not given us you're dynamic query, so that's impossible to answer...

Comment: order by cast(c.value(''@dateCreated'', ''VARCHAR(max)'') as date) DESC; This worked

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace last line to:

```
order by convert(datetime, c.value('@dateCreated', 'VARCHAR(max)'), 103) desc;
```